# Combobox value not saving for 1 specific client

Tags: c#, combobox

Not sure if anyone can be of help here, but I have a comboxbox bound to a viewmodel property, on a form who's value is set by an event.  It is working in house, but there is one client where the event fires, the value is set (I know because I added some logging), but their screen is not updated.  I have a copy of the database, and I mirror the steps and it works.  Any ideas why that could be happening?  I included the code below, but it is pretty basic.

```
private void ViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "TriggerId")
    {
         Method();
    }
 }



private void Method()
{
    ComboBoxSelectedProperty = null;

    if (TriggerId != null)
    {
        var object = Work.ObjectStore.GetById((int)TriggerId);

        if (object != null)
        {
          ComboBoxSelectedProperty = Work.AssociatedObjectStore.GetByObjenct(object);
            }

            NotifyPropertyChanged("ComboboxSourceSource");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the XAML code containing the ComboBox itself? Perhaps, it would be useful to see how it is bound to your ViewModel ;)